# Pandas duplicate equivalent to isna sum

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have any output that counts the number of na values in my dataframe using this logic

```
df.isna().sum()
```

```
col1   8
col2   0
```

And would like the same thing, but with duplicates although I don't see a full df approach to this - only column by column

How can I leverage something like

```
df.duplicated().any().sum()
```

Without specifying column by column like `df['col1'].duplicated().any().sum()`

Comment: `df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated()).sum()`?

Comment: i do get an error ```TypeError: duplicated() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'```

Comment: Oh, remove the () insdide apply

Comment: excellent! and if i wanted to include counts of 0 duplicates...an any() argument doesn't seem to work